# In Scala return value itself for default pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

For `value: Any` I need to check one string case.
For rest cases should return `value` itself.
What is the right syntax: `case _ => _ ?`

```
def foo(value: Any) = value match {
  case x: String => if (x == "cond") None else x
  case _ => _ // Compiler -> Not found value x$1. Unbound placeholder parameter
}
```

Comment: Just return `None` or `Some(value)` (depending on your app logic) if you don't care about a non matched parameter, the error is telling you that you cannot return a placeholder.

Comment: Pattern matching on types violates parametricity - http://typelevel.org/blog/2014/11/10/why_is_adt_pattern_matching_allowed.html.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply use some (arbitrary) identifier rather than `_`:

```
def foo(value: Any) = value match {
  case x: String => if (x == "cond") None else x
  case other => other
}
```

However, it is not best practice to return `None` in some cases, if you're not returning `Some` in the other cases. A more correct version would be:

```
def foo(value: Any) = value match {
  case "cond" => None
  case other => Some(other)
}
```

Then in either case you have an object of type `Option`.

Answer (score 5):

Simple as well is this plain `if-else` expression,

```
def foo(value: Any) = if (value == "cond") None else Some(value)
```

A bit more elaborate is this,

```
def foo(value: Any) = Option(value).find( _ != "cond" )
```

which delivers `None` only if `value` equates `"cond"`. Consider also using a for comprehension as follows,

```
def foo(value: Any) = for (v <- Option(value) if v != "cond") yield v
```